# broadcast and network in netplan

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface

This is my netplan configuration:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.88.13/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.88.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
    enp2s8:
      addresses: [192.168.0.10/24]
```

The previous format (/etc/network/interfaces) included the information of "network" and "broadcast".

```
broadcast 192.168.0.255
network 192.168.0.0
```

Now, where do I put this information in the new netplan format?. Thanks

note: I did not find this information on [netplan examples](https://netplan.io/examples)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not needed. The CIDR format (`10.0.2.15/24`) contains the netmask, out of which the network number and broadcast address can be calculated with the provided IP.